# Use that $a^5\equiv a\pmod 5$ and if $(a,5) = 1$ then prove $a^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Use that $a^5\equiv a\pmod 5$ and if $(a,5) = 1$ then prove $a^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$

I´ve been trying to solve this but I don’t get any where

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.
Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Divide both sides by $a$. You are allowed to do this because $a$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Look for what we call Gauss Theorem.

Comment: Use the theorem: If $d\mid bc$ and $(d,b)=1$ then $d\mid c.$ Where $a=5, b=a,$ and $c=???$

Comment: If nothing else helps, just calculate $(\pm1)^4$ and $(\pm2)^4$, also, observing $(\pm2)^2\equiv -1\pmod5$ might help.

Comment: Cancel $a$ using the linked rule.

Answer (score 0):

$a^{5} \equiv a \pmod 5 \implies 5|(a^{5}-a)=a(a^{4}-1)\implies a(a^{4}-1)=5k%$ for some integer $k$. Since $\gcd(a,5) =1,$ and by the uniqueness of prime factorizations, $5$ is a prime factor of the LHS, but not a prime factor of $a$. Hence, $5$ must be a prime factor of $a^{4} -1$ so that $5|(a^{4}-1) \implies a^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod 5.$